# Convergence of $\mathbb{E}[f]$ over Poisson/Binomial $\mathbb{E}_{X\sim\text{Bin}(n,\lambda/n)}[f]\rightarrow\mathbb{E}_{X\sim\text{Poi}(\lambda)}[f]$

Tags: limits, probability-theory, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

**Background:**
The sequence of Binomial distributions $\text{Bin}(n,p_n)$ with parameters $(n,p_n)$ is known to converge as $n\rightarrow \infty$ to the Poisson distribution $\text{Poi}(\lambda)$ if $p_n\cdot n\rightarrow \lambda$.  A special case of this is given by the following choice $p_n=\lambda/n$.

I would like to claim that the same convergence holds when I move to the expected values (under $\text{Bin}(n,p_n)$ and $\text{Poi}(\lambda)$) for a given function $f:\mathbb{N}_0\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$.

**Setup and question:** Given a function $f:\mathbb{N}_0\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$, non-negative, non-decreasing and convex (in the discrete sense) over the domain $\mathbb{N}_0$, I would like to show that the following holds

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}_{X\sim\text{Bin}(n,\lambda/n)}[f]= \mathbb{E}_{X\sim\text{Poi}(\lambda)}[f],
\end{equation}

i.e. that I can 'interchange' the expected value and the limiting operation and conclude.

**What I have tried**:

1. What makes this challenging is the fact that $f$ is not bounded. For example, I would like this result to hold for polynomials, and beyond.
2. I think it should be easy to show that if the left hand side is unbounded, so is the RHS, so we have equality in this case.
3. Hence, we can restrict to the case where we assume $\mathbb{E}_{X\sim\text{Poi}(\lambda)}[f]<\infty$. I have tried pursuing different directions e.g. Tannery's theorem, dominated/monotone convergence, even Fatou's Lemma, though I do not seem to be able to find the "right combination" or idea.

**Thank you!**

**Edit**: a partial answer is available when one cares only about the moments, i.e. for the special choice of $f(k)=k^d$ [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167212/convergence-of-moments-of-binomial-to-poisson).

I need a more general answer that applies beyond this case.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem will get you part of the way there, but the rest of the way (from one of the three modes of convergence described there to convergence in mean or convergence of the mean) is more problem-specific.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, though this applies when the function is bounded -- not my case. Unless I am missing something, obviously.

Comment: No, it is for the general continuous setting. The proof uses the portmanteau theorem, which involves bounded continuous functions. But again, it does not get you all the way to convergence of the expectation.

Comment: Idea: let $f_n(k)=\frac{f(k) p_n(k)}{q(k)}$ where $p_n$ is the binomial PMF and $q$ is the Poisson PMF. Then $f_n \to f$ pointwise, and $f_n$ is uniformly integrable with respect to $q$ (just use any $\delta<1$ as your witness for any $\epsilon$. So it suffices to show $f_n$ is tight, with respect to $q$, i.e. that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $K_\epsilon$ such that for all $n$, $\sum_{k=K_\epsilon}^\infty |f_n(k)| q(k) < \epsilon$ i.e. $\sum_{k=K^\epsilon}^\infty |f(k)| p_n(k) < \epsilon$.

Comment: This tells you that $f$ can only grow so fast at infinity: it can grow exponentially fast, but generally not factorially fast, unless $\lambda<1$.

Comment: (I changed notation between $K_\epsilon$ and $K^\epsilon$, too lazy to fix it now. Anyway, I hope that helps.)

Comment: Actually I screwed up the claim of uniform integrability, in actuality you need $|f_n(k)| q(k)=|f(k)| p_n(k)<\epsilon$ for all $n$ and all sufficiently large $k$ (since $q(k) \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$), but in this setting that is just a weaker version of the tightness requirement anyway, so the inequality I said three comments back is really what you have to grapple with.

Comment: Thank you @Ian for the suggestion! There is only one point I do not fully understand: even if I have f_n uniform integrable and tight, what argument do I use to conclude the desired convergence of expected values?

Comment: Once you have those two things (and pointwise convergence), it follows from the Vitali convergence theorem.

Comment: Hi all, @Ian, some food for thoughts: I think the Binomial distribution $\text{Bin}(n,\lambda/n)$ is always dominated by the Poisson distribution $\text{Poi}(\lambda)$ in the sense of convex ordering between distributions. Has anyone come across this? I think with this it would be trivial to conclude as $\lim\sup \mathbb{E}_{\text{Bin}(n,\lambda/n)}[f] \le \mathbb{E}_{\text{Poi}(\lambda)}[f]$. Substituting $\text{Poi}(\lambda)$ with $\lim\sup\text{Bin}(n,\lambda/n)$ in the integral on the RHS gives the same claim of the "reversed Fatou's Lemma" which is what is missing to conclude. Thoughts?

Comment: That seems plausible. Is $f$ actually strictly increasing because of this "discrete convexity"? With that you would get stochastic dominance of $f(X_n)$ as well.

Comment: @Ian, $f$ is i) non-negative, ii) non-decreasing, and iii) discrete-convex. That is, $f(x)\ge0$, $f(x+1)\ge f(x)$, $f(x+1)-f(x)\ge f(x)-f(x-1)$.

Note that this does not imply $f$ strictly increasing. 

Essentially discrete convex means that its piecewise linear extension to $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ is convex in the usual sense.

Comment: Oh, nonstrictly convex, I see. Then you...might not have stochastic dominance anymore after applying $f$? Not totally sure.